# getElementById inside an apex composition

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am having a difficult time trying to get an input text value from an element that is inside a template.

I notice when inspecting the page that between the tags of define and the form the page is adding a new span.

When the below form is outside the define section the javascript works fine and the inspect element looks like:

```
j_id0:theForm:billingCity
```

However, when i save it inside the define section a new element is added and the element looks like

```
j_id0:j_id2:theForm:billingCity
```

The VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="XXXX" extensions="YYY" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<title>VF Title</title>
<apex:composition template="PortalSiteTemplate">
<apex:define name="body">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Account Details
            </legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <apex:inputText value="{!billingCity}" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="City" id="billingCity" />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </apex:form>
</apex:define>
</apex:composition>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verAcc(){
        var city;
        city = document.getElementById("{!$Component.theForm.billingCity}").value;
        alert(city);
    }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: first find out j_id0:j_id2 which element Ids. when you find give some name to those elements and after that use `document.getElementById("{!$Component.FirstElement.SecondElement.theForm.billingCity}")`

Comment: Ratan, that is what I am trying to do, but i cant find it, the define and composition doesnt allow id, I notice in between the define and the form a span is created

Comment: I guess it will be your apex:page and apex:component tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this page is part of the composition, they are actually 2 pages involve, the second VF page in my example is called: PortalSiteTemplate.

I have fixed it by adding the id to that page:

```
<apex:page controller="..." .language="en-US" id="temp">
```

Then I was able to use:

```
city = document.getElementById("{!$Component.temp.theForm.billingCity}").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `getElementsByClassName()` to retrieve the values of the `inputText` which has been specified by `styleClass="form-control"`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  //it will display inputText value
    alert(elements[i].value);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the page is adding an extra "id" between component and form so {!$Component.theForm} return null, please note that I state the id is rendering as j_id0:j_id2:theForm:billingCity and not as j_id0:theForm:billingCity, otherwise that would work

Comment: then, use document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');

Comment: updated my answer, it will work

Comment: did that solve your purpose? If so, then close the ques

Comment: It could solve but it is not the right way, in this sample was one field, but the form contains hundreds, I have found the issue and create an answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the $component hierarchy. You have actually identified the issue yourself by mentioning that an additional ID is being added when form is outside the define section.

To solve this give an ID to the apex:define like this:

```
<apex:define name="body" id="thedefine">
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Account Details
        </legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <apex:inputText value="{!billingCity}" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="City" id="billingCity" />
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</apex:form>
```

Now, refer as follows:

```
city = document.getElementById("{!$Component.thedefine.theForm.billingCity}").value
```

This should work.

A general note: For ease of use I prefer using jQuery, where I can refer to the ID directly using a wildcard as follows:

```
$j('[id$="billingCity"]').value
```

Give jQuery a try.

Let me know if this doesnt work.. My code may contain scemantic errors :)

Comment: HI that is pretty close but define doesnt allow adding an id, I have create an answer to close this question